# How to give white space between currency and currency symbol Magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2

**Below Image does not have any space between currency and currency symbol.**

[image: With out space image]

[image]

**After did that step it look like my currency symbol changed in English word instead of Arabic**

[image]

Comment: You can give space from Admin where currency symbols are saved.

Comment: @Dotsquares Thank you for giving me your valuable answer, Actually i have two store view on site.I given their white space which place you say but there I got the issue after giving the space my currency symbol changed to in English

Comment: I hope you have performed the operation that someone posted below. If you have, can you please let me know if you encountered any errors or you can share with us URL?

Comment: Yes I have performed the below step it's is work but my currency symbol change to English formate please check i have attache the image in question

Comment: I tried the below post and it seems working as expected nothing getting any change English... but let me check more in code files but we can do

Answer (score 0):

To add white space between currency and currency symbol in Magento 2.4.3, you can follow these steps:

1. Log in to your Magento admin panel.
2. Go to Stores > Configuration.
3. Under Currency Options, select the currency that you want to edit.
4. Expand the "Number/Currency Formatting" section.
5. In the "Currency Symbol" field, add a space after the currency symbol. For example, if your currency symbol is "$", add a space after it, so it becomes "$ ".
6. Click "Save Config" to save your changes.

Once you have completed these steps, the currency symbol and amount should be separated by a white space.

> **After given their white space and got the issue after giving the space**
> **my currency symbol changed to in English then performed below action:**

I see, it sounds like adding the space after the currency symbol caused your currency to display in English instead of your preferred language.

To fix this issue, you can try the following steps:

1. Go to Stores > Currency > Currency Rates and check if the currency rates for your preferred language are correctly set. If not, update the rates and save the changes.
2. Go to Stores > Configuration > General > Locale Options and make sure that the locale for your preferred language is selected.
3. Go to Stores > Configuration > Currency Setup > Currency Options and set the "Allow Currencies" option to only include the currency you want to use for your preferred language.
4. In the "Number/Currency Formatting" section for the currency you want to edit, remove the space you added after the currency symbol and click "Save Config".
5. Finally, clear your Magento cache and refresh the page to see if the issue has been resolved.

Hopefully, these steps will help you to fix the issue and display your preferred language with the correct currency symbol.

Comment: Navneet Sharma Hello above step already configured in system

Comment: Have you checked complete description which I describe above... I edited my answer few mins before.

Comment: Yes i have checked but i didn't get this "Number/Currency Formatting" part in the admin

Comment: In that case, we will need to review the code to see if there are any other functions or processes that are interfering with the currency language. It's possible that there is another area of the code that is causing the issue, and we will need to investigate further to determine the cause. Because above steps does work as expected. Either you can share with me sftp with new user or it's up to you...